# Why this trivial hint is required?

Tags: dafny

I wonder why Dafny requires the commented hint in http://rise4fun.com/Dafny/8sl7
to validate the assertion?
Could someone explain it?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that Dafny is only willing to unroll a function a limited number of times when constructing proofs. Proving that assertion requires unrolling applyMapSeq three times.

I suggest adding some postconditions to applyMapSeq that will help Dafny with this and with other proofs. Here's the signature I have in mind:

```
function applyMapSeq<U,V> (f: map<U,V>, xs:seq<U> ): (ys:seq<V>)
  requires (set x | x in xs) <= domain(f)
  ensures  |ys| == |xs|
  ensures  forall i :: 0 <= i < |xs| ==> ys[i] == f[xs[i]]
```

You can see at http://rise4fun.com/Dafny/Vibu that, with these additional postconditions, Dafny can verify your assertion.